# STL vs Qt Какие контейнеры оставить в проекте?

Tags: qt, stl, сравнение

При слиянии двух больших частей проекта(каждую часть делала своя мини-тима) оказалось, что одна команда использовала stl контейнеры, другая qt контейнеры. Очевидно, что лучше весь проект держать на одних контейнерах, чтобы потом не было путаницы, и не тратиться на преобразования из stl :: map в Qmap например. С вопросом того, что это ошибка , понятно, надо было договориться заранее. Но вот теперь надо работать с тем, что есть.

Есть ли у кого рекомендации и информация по тому, какие контейнеры работают быстрее(потому, что критерий памяти для нас не так важен, а в остальном насколько я понимаю, они примерно равны) и в каких случаях, чтобы мы могли определиться с тем, какие всё-таки оставить. И какие есть инструменты по автоматизированному переводу кода с одних библиотек на другие?

Или если проще, как определиться, какие контейнеры оставить и какие для этого есть инструменты?

PS для обобщения вопроса, будем считать что все используемые контейнеры имеют аналоги в обеих либах.

Comment: Мне казалось, что подобные вопросы закрывают из-за невозможности дать объективный ответ. Qt-контейнеры используют принцип сopy-on-write и повсеместно используются в Qt-API. STL-контейнеры будут быстрее (если не учитывать сopy-on-write). Вероятно, нужно отталкиваться от частоты использования Qt-шных методов.

Comment: @needKVAS,я понимаю, что тут для каждого случая своё, я постарался максимально обобщить вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать объективный ответ. 1 кто быстрее
2 какие есть инструменты чтобы переписать часть кода автоматизированно. Хочу обратить внимание, что вопрос "как определиться какие оставить " и вопрос : "какие мне оставить", это разные вопросы, и я использовал именно первый потому, что его можно использовать для общего случая и можно дать объективный ответ.

Comment: Qt-шники в коде используют STL контейнеры и STL умные указатели. Заменяют Q_DECL_OVERRIDE на override и т.д.